# How to configure the libraries in datasource to connect AS400 with JT400 deployed in Websphere 8.5?

Tags: db2, datasource, cobol, websphere-8, jt400

I configured a datasource in Websphere, using JT400.jar

[image]

And I've specified custom properties:

- dataSourceName
- databaseName
- driver: toolbox
- libraries: ABC, CDE
- naming: system
- packageLibrary: QC

Test connection message:
[image]

When I executed the web webservice, it worked, but it's not considering the libraries that I specified in the properties of datasource, it executed with the library by default, have I forgot to set some property?

My service executes a stored procedure in DB2, this SP executes a CBL File, and this impact in some tables that can found in the library "ABC" or "POL"(by default). Actually, When I executed it impacts in POL.

Comment: This might be a long shot, but I noticed in the doc: "List of system libraries, separated by commas or spaces"

Can you try libraries as "ABC CDE" instead of "ABC, CDE" ?

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but it doesn't work, still reading from default library

Comment: @marks, the datasource has been modified "n" times, should i restart websphere?

Comment: Yes, if you're making datasource changes I would recommend a restart